# how long SwipeRefreshLayout

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout

i need to know the end of time swipeRefresh 
i need relay to do the progressDialog while swipe and the progress cancel when swipe end

```
final ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(context);
        progress.setTitle("Chargement");
        progress.setMessage("Veuillez patienter pendant que nous lancons la 
        mise a jour");
        progress.show();

        Runnable progressRunnable = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                progress.cancel();
            }
        };

        Handler pdCanceller = new Handler();
        pdCanceller.postDelayed(progressRunnable, 16000);
```

Comment: what do you do when you swipe to refresh? you request for fresh data?

Comment: Yes  fresh data ! i need to show the ProgressDialog  and cancel them when the swipe finish

Comment: where do you ask for new data?

Comment: from model 
public void onRefresh() {
        if (inNetwork()) {
            parent().sync().requestSync(Sanction.AUTHORITY);

Comment: So when you get your data back fire an events that advise your fragment/activity that the update is completed. Then there hide progress dialog